# I'm trying to stop SaveFileDialog from being prompted from elseif DialogResult.No (and cancel)

Tags: prompt, savefiledialog

Basically I'm a beginner at this sort of thing, and I'm trying to practice by creating my own Note Pad application, by similarly replicating Microsoft's Notepad. I have searched online for hours to no prevail.

So the problem, I've began with the item 'New' in the ToolStripMenu, when pressed, it prompts the user with the message "Do you want to save the changes to this document?", if the user presses Yes, the SaveFileDialog shows, and the user can save it to wherever he/she pleases. If the user presses no, the information in the RichTextDialogBox is cleared, and if the user presses cancel, it returns without making any changes, as planned. However, when I click the 'No' and/or 'Cancel' buttons, it still prompts the user with a SaveFileDialog box. Is it possible anyone could help me change my code slightly so that it stops the buttons 'No' and 'Cancel' from prompting the user with a SaveFileDialog?

```
    Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click
    Dim intResult As Integer = Nothing
    Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog
    dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
    intResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes made to this document?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)
    If dlg.ShowDialog = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
    ElseIf intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
    End If
    If intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel Then
        Return
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is because you are calling the dialog as part of your If conditional test

Try the following

```
Private Sub NewToolStripMenuItem_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles NewToolStripMenuItem.Click

    Dim intResult As Integer = Nothing
    Dim dlg As SaveFileDialog = New SaveFileDialog

    dlg.Filter = "Text File (*.txt)|*.txt"
    intResult = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to save the changes made to this document?", "Warning", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel)

    If intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Yes Then
        dlg.ShowDialog
        RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)
    ElseIf intResult = Windows.Forms.DialogResult.No Then
        RichTextBox1.Clear()
    Else
        Return
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: Now it's quite the opposite. Everything I had planned (Clear information on DialogResult.No, or return back to normal on DialogResult.Cancel) still works, but now DialogResult.Yes doesn't prompt the user with a SaveFileDialog box, and it highlights "RichTextBox1.SaveFile(dlg.FileName, RichTextBoxStreamType.RichText)" on Line 10, and gives an error "ArgumentException was unhandled, empty path name is not legal".

Comment: Inside the if block checking for Yes, insert the following line dlg.ShowDialog before the line RichTextBox1.SaveFile